# How do I create/allow a drop-down search option for a tinyint variable?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, drop-down-menu, vbscript, dropdown

In one of my computer programming classes, we were given a project to allow users to select whether they want to filter results for a Lead or a Prospect. In our database a Lead = 0, whereas a Prospect = 1. My group and I can't seem to figure a way to formulate a dropdown. We've tried mimicking our "Status" dropdown, however, I don't think that is the solution that would fix all of our problems.

Here is the current code that allows our users to view/filter Open/Closed results. It also allows them to search for a business by typing in the name and also the option to search by phoine number:

```
<td><select size="1" name="OpenClosed" class="small"><option value="0" <%If OpenClosed = 0 Then rw " selected"%>>Open</option><option value="1" <%If OpenClosed = 1 Then rw " selected"%>>Closed</option></td>
<td><input name="name" value="<%=Request("name")%>" class="medium" placeholder="Business Unit or Group Name" /></td>
<td><input name="phone1" value="<%=Request("phone1")%>" class="medium" placeholder="Phone Number" /></td>
```

Is there an easy way to create a drop-down that allows the user to select whether they want to search for a Lead or Prospect?

Comment: Why can't you use the code you posted?

Comment: What kind of computer programming classes are we talking about. Webforms, MVC?

Comment: What is the extension of your file? .asp or .aspx ?

Comment: @SearchAndResQ The file extension is .asp

Comment: @SeanLange Which line would you recommend using?

Comment: @VDWWD Talking about MVC

Comment: The one with the combobox in it?